# jquery add listener to appended content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-append

I have some jQuery code like this:

```
$("#add").click(function(event){
    $("#list").append('<a class="remove" href="#">x</a>');

    return false;
});

$('.remove').live('click', function(){
    alert("123");
});
```

If one clicked on class=remove I would like it to alert 123. This doesn't happen though. I think this is a simple idea but I must be missing something.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Live is deprecated, use on

```
$(document).on('click','.remove',function(){
alert("123");
});
```

Comment: and you do the document click to bind to something that is present at load time

Comment: I see that it does do event delegation in the manner that you are using it. Interesting. Thanks for this.

Comment: Yes, if a selector is present it is a delegated event handler. Read more here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: This is definitely the best answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to add element and bind event without delegation:

```
$("#add").click(function(event){
    $("<a />", {
        "class": "remove",
        href: "#",
        text: "x"
    }).on("click", function() {
        alert("123");
        return false;
    }).appendTo("#list");

    return false;
});
```

Avoid using `live` method, since it was deprecated and finally removed in the last version of jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

try on delegate function..since you are apending that to `list`... you can use `#list` which is better in performance that the `document`

```
 $('#list').on('click','.remove', function(){
     alert("123");
});
```

you can go through the link to read more about [on()](http://jq4you.blogspot.com/2013/02/jquery-direct-and-delegate-on-event.html) event